# Square and equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, plane-geometry

> *CDEF* is a square, *CBF* and *BEA* are equilateral triangles. Find angle $x$.

[image]

What I have found at the moment:

- $\angle BEF =15^{\circ}, \angle AED =135^{\circ} $
- I managed to find the length of $BE$ and use the Law of Cosines in $\triangle ADE$ to find $AD$ and to use the Law of Cosines one more time to get the $\cos \angle ADE$, but I didn't get good numbers.

Maybe there should be an analytical way to solve the problem.

Comment: FWIW $\angle AED=135$ not $150$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Simple angle chasing leads to,
$$\angle CBD=\angle CDB=\angle EFB=\angle EBF=15^{\circ}$$
Observe,
$$\triangle BCD\cong \triangle BEF\implies BD=BF=AB\implies \angle BDA=\angle BAD=45^{\circ}$$
Since $\angle CDB=15^{\circ}$ and $\angle BDF=\angle BFD=75^{\circ},$
$$\angle BDA=75^{\circ}-x\implies \boxed{x=30^{\circ}}$$

Comment: Great solution. You've missed part $\angle ABD=\angle ABF-\angle EBF+\angle ABC-\angle CBD=90°$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you. I have not included $\angle ABD=90^{\circ}$ since there are several easy ways to arrive at it.(Example: $\angle DBF=30^{\circ}$ and $\angle ABF=60^{\circ}$)